# How can I pass a function which takes parameter from command line arguments in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

How can I pass a function which takes parameter from command line arguments in pytest parametrize fixture? I'm doing so as depending on the department, I'm getting related tests from yaml file, which I want to pass to parametrize.

test_run.py

```
def getTests(dept):        
    for dept_test in dept_test_info[dept]["test"]:        
        allowed_tests.append(dept_test)     
return allowed_tests

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test",getTests(dept))
```

But I would like dept to be coming as command line argument when I run the pytest.

python pytest test_run.py --dept="anydept"

Comment: Even if you could, you shouldn't

Comment: Oh, is there any other way to achieve the same? My dept name comes as command line argument. and I would like to pick the tests on the basis of the dept name.

Comment: tests should be deterministic. you shouldn't be passing any parameters through the command line. if you want to run the yaml depending on department, hardcode the mapping or make it so it can dynamically determine the filename to load

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the last part of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this question:

1. You could use environment variables to pass in the parameters to the test code.
2. You shouldn't do this at all.  Tests should ideally not depend on changing values unless the test code themselves is creating them (using random() or similar is ok, but not random parameters being passed in by the testing user).  Instead, have your test code contain all the departments you want to test against:

```py
def getTests():   
    test_departments = ["accounting", "hr" "research and design", "engineering"]    
    for dept in my_departments: 
        for dept_test in dept_test_info[dept]["test"]:        
            allowed_tests.append(dept_test)     
return allowed_tests

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test",getTests(dept))
```